# Modifying an attribute's value through a method

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code I tried to work on. I tried to modify the 'self.odometer_reading' attribute to 20000 by making adding a method with a parameter 'mileage' that equates to 'self.odometer_reading' attribute.
In the bottom part. I set the argument for mileage 20000 and I get the error 'TypeError: Car() takes no arguments' Can someone double check my code and see what I did wrong. Thank you.

```
class Car():
    def __int__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        descriptive_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return descriptive_name

    def read_odometer(self):
        print('This car has ' + str(self.odometer_reading) + ' ' + 'mileage on it.')

    # add a parameter to update attribute in a method
    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        self.odometer_reading = mileage

the_car = Car('Audi', 'R8', '2008')
print(the_car.get_descriptive_name())
the_car.update_odometer(20000)
the_car.read_odometer()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of `__init__` you used `__int__` that's the problem

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        descriptive_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return descriptive_name

    def read_odometer(self):
        print('This car has ' + str(self.odometer_reading) + ' ' + 'mileage on it.')

    # add a parameter to update attribute in a method
    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        self.odometer_reading = mileage

the_car = Car('Audi', 'R8', '2008')
print(the_car.get_descriptive_name())
the_car.update_odometer(20000)
the_car.read_odometer()
```

```
Output:
2008 Audi R8
This car has 20000 mileage on it.
```

[image]

Comment: @user109503 no mention

Comment: oh wait i tried to fix that and i still get the same error

Comment: TypeError: Car() takes no arguments

Comment: just copy and paste it in your ide and run it does not show error

Comment: In which ide are you using, It' s working perfectly for me

Comment: im using pycharm. I just restarted pycharm and I got it with no errors already thanks!